# Позиционирование HTML Canvas на странице

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

Столкнулся с проблемой позиционирования Canvas на своей странице. Цель: добавить подсвечивающие неоновым цветом зелёные линии на страницу. Canvas прикрывает собой другие элементы страницы: невозможно нажать на кнопки, они перестали подсвечиваться.

Как видите: тег canvas находится в самом начале тега body. Я уже пытался написать его где-нибудь в середине, в header, в самом начале, но результат тот же: он прикрывает остальные элементы.

[image]

---

Код CSS

[image]

---

Код JS

[image]

---

Макет. Вот так должны располагаться линии на странице.

[image]

---

Линии рисуются, но проблема остаётся нерешённой.

[image]

Заранее спасибо.

P.S мой первый вопрос на этом сайте)

Comment: Ошибся... . Куда пропали описания для каждого изображения ? В принципе я оставил комментарии. Надеюсь я понятно описал свою проблему.

Comment: Вы уверены что понимаете как именно работает canvas? советую почитать. А по вопросу: Как вариант, можете использовать не canvas а изображение на заднем фоне. Либо если хотите именно cavas, то либо рисуйте на нем все элементы, либо просто используйте z-index для поднятия всех кнопок выше канваса.

Comment: Отредактируйте пожалуйста вопрос и добавьте код текстом, а не картинкой

Comment: css `canvas{pointer-events:none}`

Comment: Разметку, css, js и остальной код нужно вставлять текстом, а не картинками